# What datastructure should i use storing and recording events?

Tags: events, data-structures

I want to record events based on on a date. I also want people to be able to search for event based on a particular date and the person who recorded the event.

For example:
Person A logs in and sees a calendar, click on a day/date and records an event for that day.
Person B logs in and sees a calendar, click on a day/date and records an event for that day.
Person C comes and does the same thing.

Note that either of these persons can record more than one event.

I want to be able record this data effectively in the database and search for these events based on a number of different criteria.

Please can someone help me with a data structure for this problem?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409053/time-calendar-data-structure

Comment: As with any other DB design, you should create a table schema that contains all of the data you need, and no data that you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

### Person

- ID
- Name

### PersonalEvent

- ID
- Person
- Name
- Date

Comment: What about the event details? Something tells me this seems too simple?